# r caret train and predict after tuning

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret

I'm currently working on a research paper.
My dataset consists of daily stock index data with a predictor that says UP or DOWN.

In total I use 20% of my dataset to tune the parameters. Based on the code below I found that I should use sigma = 0.05 and C = 25.

Now, I want to train 50% on my dataset based on these settings and make a prediction on the other 50% of the set.

Could anyone explain how I should do this? I can't find how I should proceed in caret's documentation.

```
### MODELS
## SetUp Training
trainControl <- trainControl(method="cv", index = fit_on, indexOut = pred_on, savePredictions = TRUE)
metric <- "Accuracy"

## Parameter tuning
# SVM
set.seed(1908)
grid_rf <- expand.grid(C = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50), sigma = c(0,025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5,4,4.5,5,7,5,10,15))
fit.svm <- train(class~., data=dataCombined, method="svmRadial", metric=metric, preProc=c("range"),trControl=trainControl, tuneGrid = grid_rf)
```

Many thanks!

Best,

Mathijs

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already created a predefined test and train set. Therefore, I don't need to create a new data partition.

Comment: what's your `dataCombined`? Here is what you could do: First divide the data into two parts 50% train, 50% test (e.g. using `createDataPartition` if you don't have the stratified data partitioned already). Now use your best-fit model tuned with on the train dataset with grid-search CV (which will use held-out folds automatically to select the best hyper-parameter values) straightaway to predict the test data.